# text super thin on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, text

http://wilsonschlamme.com

Is my artist website that I decided to build from scratch myself. I did some html css work many years ago, and barely know what I'm doing. However, after picking through examples on the web, I'm slowly re learning. That is what I've put together.

PROBLEM: on the info page, clearly you can see on MOBILE device like an iphone that the text is sprawling down in a thin line, like a waterfall. This effect can be mimicked as well if one were to make their browser page very thin.

Wondering if anyone has any suggestions on how to keep that text proportionate to the page. I know what's happening, I'm keeping the text roughly centered to the page using padding/margins. Well, this works great when the site is displayed on a computer, but on mobile, the text is then displayed SUPER thin.

Problem is, I'm not sure how else to achieve this on a full web browser. Obviously, this is unacceptable at the moment. 
Any thoughts are very much appreciated.

*I also notice that my little copyright text at the bottom of the page is displayed far to the right on mobile devices, while it works fine on web browsers. This is a much more minor issue compared to the one above. Thoughts on this would be awesome as well!

Thanks very much,
-Wilson

Comment: Can you insert images or examples of what you have right now.

Comment: This is what it looks like on a normal web browser: https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/29370814496/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: And on a mobile: https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/29405483495/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: CSS: https://www.flickr.com/photos/77598212@N03/29370939446/in/dateposted-public/

Comment: **Update. Not sure if anyone is reading this thread anymore. I came up with a solution, but a very clumsy one. Just centered the text via html, and made the margin css properties quite small. It doesn't look great, but it works. Any better solutions would be appreciated. Thank you. http://www.wilsonschlamme.com